# Powershell equivalent for unix command "Uniq -c"

Tags: powershell

I would like to display the multiple lines with the number of frequencies for a file output. I need that for the Powershell as a one-liner. It should work as a one-liner like under unix with "uniq -c". This is not possible with

```
gc file.log | sort | get-unique
```

Comment: But I see only one line?

Comment: I use a file, where many items are included.

Answer (score 2):

Are you probably looking for [Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7)? It will include the `Count` of occurrences for each item:

```
gc file.log | group -NoElement | sort Count -Desc
```

Note that PowerShell works with objects, not text. So the result is actually a list of objects that have a `Count` and a `Name` property. Powershell tries its best to display the objects along with their properties in the console in a readable format and therefore truncates some of the values (for *display* only).

If you want the plain-text output exactly as in linux, you can add this:

```
gc file.log | group -NoElement | sort Count -Desc | foreach { "{0} {1}" -f $_.Count, $_.Name }
```

I would not recommend doing this though, if you want to process the results further. Working with objects, not text, is the "PowerShell way".

Comment: That seems fine, but ir cut the elements of the file: For Example the output looks like: 
Count Name
----- ----
    1 c:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_…
    1 c:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_…
    1 c:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_…
    1 c:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_… The Input of the file are Filenames with the whole path. I need the whole path with filename in the result.

Comment: this solution works very good for me. Thanks a lot !!